# What is best practice for creating tab bar navigation in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, xcode9, swift4

I'm creating a tab bar based app. What is best practice in Xcode 9 and swift 4 to create and manage navigation between key sections of an app. I have five sections, "feed", "club", "record", "profile", "more".

Currently I'm using action segue "show". However there are a lot of segues forth and back between the five sections and it becomes difficult to handle. So I assume there is a better way built in.

I know there is a "Tab Bar Controller" in Interface Builder, or I can potentially create the app wide tab controller programatically. What is best practice?

Comment: I guess TabBarController would be my first thought.. Why would you even consider implementing it yourself

Comment: Not sure... started off on the wrong foot I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to implement it by ourself. Just use UITabBarViewController. You can create your own subclass of UITabBarViewController and inside init setup everything in code or you can use Storyboards for that.